# Subquery as a condition in a WHERE statement

Tags: mysql

I haven't had much practice with subqueries and am having an extremely difficult time writing this query. What I basically need to do is select all records from the `user_info` table that match the following criteria.

`user_info` and `otherTable` contain `user_id` field that relates the two tables. I need to select all fields from `user_info` if the `$state` variable equals `ot.state` AND the `ot.user_id = ui.user_id` while still maintaining all the conditions of the `user_info` WHERE statement.

```
SELECT * FROM users_info ui
WHERE cond1=1 AND cond2=2 AND (ot.state = $state AND ui.user_id = ot.user_id)
(
   SELECT * FROM otherTable as ot
   WHERE ui.user_id = ot.user_id
)
```

Note I am confident I am wayyy off with my query,
 I appreciate any clarification on how to accomplish this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should prepared statements and bound variables instead of injecting variables into your SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you just need to join the 2 tables together and apply the rest of your constraints:

```
select
from
users_info ui
inner join otherTable  ot
on ui.user_id = ot.user_id
where
cond1=1 AND 
cond2=2 
AND ot.state = $state
```

If you want to use the sub-query:

```
select
from
users_info ui
inner join (select user_id from otherTable where state = $state) ot
on ui.user_id = ot.user_id
where
cond1=1 AND 
cond2=2
```

or you could just do use the where clause instead:

```
    select
    from
    users_info ui
    where
    cond1=1 AND 
    cond2=2 and
ui.user_id in (select user_id from otherTable where state = $state)
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew. However, this is a bit of a problem, b/c the query is dynamically created and the select statement already JOINED two tables, by the time I get to the above query, that's why I was wondering if I can just create a sub-query kind of thing so I don't have to dig in to all the condition that create the `select` statement?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but see the query I added above.